# How Do I Add product descriptions (short) to hover box in woocommerce?

Tags: php, html, css, web, woocommerce

I am using the following to add the product name and price to a hover box.

In functions.php

```
// Alter produt loop individual products 

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'new_product_defaults_wrap_open' , 20 ); //opener
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'new_product_defaults_wrap_close', 40); //closer

function new_product_defaults_wrap_open() {
  echo '<div class="product-details">';    
}
function new_product_defaults_wrap_close() {
    echo '</div><!--/.product-details-->';
}
```

In css:

```
/*The code below will simply setup the price-title area to be hidden and have a background. Please note that uou will have to change the background and height to match your website color scheme and product height  but first load it as and then adjust                                                                                      
*/

.products .product .product-details {
        position: absolute;
        background: rgba(119, 203, 109, 0.95);
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        color: #f7f7f7;
        padding: 1.618em;
        text-align: left;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 167px;
    filter: alpha(opacity=@opacity * 100);  
    -webkit-transition: all ease 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: all ease 0.4s;
        -o-transition: all ease 0.4s;
        transition: all ease 0.4s; 
  }

/* Show the that was setup above when the user hovers*/

 ul.products li.product:hover .product-details {
    filter: alpha(opacity=@opacity * 100);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  ul.products li.product a img:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
```

I got this code from https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us/articles/203103707-Products-layout-show-price-on-hover-like-Peddlar-theme-?page=1#comment_203088363.

I would like to add the product short description to the .product-details class, but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WooCommerce Product description uses `the_excerpt()` function... try like this...

```
function new_product_defaults_wrap_open() {
  echo '<div class="product-details">';
  the_excerpt();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked, but the short description is above the product name. How do I get the Product name on top and the Short description below? Thanks!

Comment: With as much rep as you have, why couldn't you include a proper explanation? That said, this is an attempt to answer the question, therefore it should not have been flagged and should not be recommended for deletion in the LQPRQ. - [From Review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11109598)

Comment: No, I was messaging the author of this answer, you just happened to be pinged because you were the only other commenter here.

Comment: OK. For the record, the code provided does add the short description to the hover text. Only need to add the line 'the_excerpt();' Adding the rest gives a error. To be honest, I wouldn't understand the explanation.

Comment: @TinyGiant, sorry for the bother, but there's no explaining to do... the one asking just maybe don't know the right function to use... and my answer provides the function he needs.. and sorry for the bother...  I've got a few down votes lately for almost all my answers.. someone hates me..

Comment: @theBIOguy can you edit your Original Post and describe what additional problems you met? currently, I don't understand your question here on comments...

Comment: @Reigel Thanks for your help. When I hover, I see the Short description on the first line and the product name on the second line (below). I want to switch them so the product name is on top and the short description is below.

Comment: can you give me a screenshot with what you have if you inspect element in your browser? I'm not sure if this is just a css problem or html markup...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102305/discussion-between-thebioguy-and-reigel).

Comment: @Reigel You're the best. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can explain why your answer solves the problem without introducing new problems and what was wrong with what the OP was doing.

Answer (score 0):

To complete and clarify on the issue regarding the order, this worked for me:

`add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 20 );`