# How to add more info (excerpt) on hover over product in WooCommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I have a Woocommerce store and I would like to display more information on hover over the product, something like this: https://www.lekarnar.com/

[image: Picture before and after hover]

I added some code in functions.php to show a part of excerpt on products page:

```
function woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title_short_description() {
    global $product;
    if ( ! $product->get_short_description() ) return;
    ?>
    
    <div itemprop="description"> <?php echo substr(apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $product->post->post_excerpt ),0,130); echo '...' ?> </div>
    <?php
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title_short_description', 5);
```

This code shows the additional text, which I want to show below everything else only on hover.

I also tried this: [How Do I Add product descriptions (short) to hover box in woocommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35135891/how-do-i-add-product-descriptions-short-to-hover-box-in-woocommerce)

But this hides the name and price of the item and shows them only on hover.

Comment: should you post more code?, it is a little complicated with one line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this code for you which should work.  Simply add it to your functions.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'wc_add_short_description' );

function wc_add_short_description() {
    global $product;

    ?>
        <div class="descShow" itemprop="description">
            <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $product->post-> post_excerpt ) ?>
        </div>
        <style>
        .descShow{
            display:none;
        }
        
        li.product:hover .descShow{
            display: block;
        }
        
        </style>
    <?php
}
```

Edit:  I added some transition effects so it hides and shows smoothly.  Use this code instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'wc_add_short_description' );

function wc_add_short_description() {
    global $product;

    ?>
        <div class="descShow" itemprop="description">
            <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $product->post-> post_excerpt ) ?>
        </div>
        <style>
        .descShow{
        max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-out;
    overflow: hidden;
        }
        
        li.product:hover .descShow{
           max-height: 1000px;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in;
        }
        
        </style>
    <?php
}
```

Edit number 2 to have the description appear over the other products. Use this code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'wc_add_short_description' );

function wc_add_short_description() {
    global $product;

    ?>
        <div class="descShow" itemprop="description">
            <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $product->post-> post_excerpt ) ?>
        </div>
        <style>
        .descShow{
        max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-out;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:2;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
   
        }
        
        li.product:hover .descShow{
           max-height: 1000px;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in;
        }
        
        
        </style>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: That's great! Thank you! It shows description only on hover as I wanted. Do you maybe also know how I can change CSS to show description on top of the product below? The same problem was here, but I can't find the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55087968/woocommerce-css-hovered-product-that-overflowes-over-product-below

Comment: @Mojca  Yes I added a new edit to my answer with the updated code.  You can use that and it will appear over the other products.

Comment: I think the first edit is great, maybe I will go with that. The second edit shows the description above everything. I don't know how to show the whole product box as one element over the product below (as it is here: https://www.lekarnar.com/). You can see on my test environment how it looks now (I made some CSS changes): https://test-environment.anaya.si/vsi-izdelki/

Comment: @Mojca I would personally go with my first edit as well. Things start to get complicated when you try to pop elements out like that.

Comment: you can use the second Edit option and add CSS min-height and min-width value to cover your whole image product on hover. Bit still need to make some adjustments with @ mediascreen to excatly cover your product, according to screen size if that can help. You can also use the hook 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item'

Answer (score 0):

you can use the second Edit option and add CSS min-height and min-width value to cover your whole image product on hover, regardless to screen size. You can also use the hook 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item'

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'wc_add_short_description' );

function wc_add_short_description() {
    global $product;

    ?>
        <div class="descShow" itemprop="description">
            <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $product->post-> post_excerpt ) ?>
        </div>
        <style>
        .descShow{
        max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-out;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:2;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
   
        }
        
        li.product:hover .descShow{
           max-height: 100%;
           min-height:100%;
           max-width: 100%;
           min-width:100%;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
        }
        
        
        </style>
    <?php
}
```